# Junit 4.12 much slower than TestNG running as ANT Task

Tags: java, ant, testng, integration-testing, junit4

Good morning everyone,

as you can read in the title, I have some serious performing issues with `Junit 4.12,ANT (Ant 1.9.2)` and `Java1.6.0_45.64`. I wrote a hole new test framework for my company because the current is messed up.

We are performing continuous integration tests with *Jenkins CI*, now using `Junit 4.12`, `Ant 1.9.2` and the `DbUnit-2.5.1` SNAPSHOT library for DB transactions on our `Oracle DB (11g)`. I am tied to use this libraries/setups because they're are part of my requirements.

So I integrated the new framework to a smaller Project (111 tests) and ran the test suite. From the *`Eclipse IDE (Mars.1)`* it took 100s (avg).

Now, so I can integrate to Jenkins, I am writing the ant target. Running the test suite with ant took much longer (~300s). Damnit...

I then rewrote the new framework for using *TestNG* (the old framework) and ran the ant target. This took only have the time.

I researched for hours on Google and found some configurations for the junit Task, like setting `forkmode=once` --> nothing changed at all.

I now gave up and I am asking more experienced developers for help. Do you hava any ideas?

Thanks in advance!